# Apache not letting me into a folder

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, httpd.conf

I've configured my httpd.conf using:

```
Directory "/Users/GMan/Public/Source/LC2">
```

I've stopped the apache server with:

```
apachectl stop
```

And then restarted it with:

```
apachectl -f /path/to/my/httpd.conf
```

And yet when I browse to my ip:

```
http://1.1.1.1
```

I see the default index.html which contains:

```
It Works!
```

I'm using a Mac with OS 10.5.  I am totally stumped and would appreciate some ideas!

G-Man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<Directory>` directive you quoted above does not tell Apache where the root of your website is in the filesystem. Instead, it's a way to specify different options, permissions, etc for certain directories.

You need to look into the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive. That tells apache where to look for your files.